# How to get values from timepicker fields against the click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have dynamically created multiple tr with timepicker. I am using wickedpicker.min.js. I want to get the values of respective timepicker value  against the anchor tag click i.e. submit click.

```
<tr>
<td id="output"></td>
<td>1001</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Disposal</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
<input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input sstart">
</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
<input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input eend">
</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
<a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent btn-sm setAttn">submit</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am using this to get the values:

```
$(document).on("click", ".setAttn", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert($(".sstart").val());
alert($(".eend").val());
});
```

Comment: What ? you want to get the time on submit is it ? if so read the `.val()` using `JavaScript` or `JQuery` use an event listener to listen to the submit click even.

Comment: Yes. When I tried to get the values it replies with the values of the first tr only.

Comment: Then where is that code you used to get that value ? post that as well error is on that code. And I see the problem you're using the same `ID` on both so the `JavaScript` will read both as one and will take the very first value.

Comment: I am using this code to get the values:
    $(document).on("click", ".setAttn", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(".sstart").val());
    alert($(".eend").val());
    });

Comment: Update it on your question not in comments.

Comment: updated question@Sand

Comment: I just checked it is alerting both values so what is the problem ?

Comment: Ya its alerting values but if i have two tr (Since I am dynamically  binding the tr to a table), then I am not getting different values. the values will be different in timepicker. On the respective button click, i want to get the timepicker's value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in this code I've used `jquery` and loops through all the `input type=text` tags and it will read all the values till the set tag type ends in the `HTML` page.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".setAttn", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".sstart").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  })

  $(".eend").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td id="output"></td>
  <td>1001</td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Disposal</td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input sstart">
  </td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input eend">
  </td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input sstart">
  </td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <input type="text" id="timepicker-24-hr" name="timepicker-24-hr" class="timepicker-24-hr mdl-textfield__input eend">
  </td>
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent btn-sm setAttn">submit</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sadaruwan12/uz5x1n4s/)

Comment: This loops thru all the inputs.  On submit I just need the values of .sstart and .eend class timepicker

Comment: Then you should have asked the question clearly. explaining what is the end result you want not just say want to get time picker values. Answer updated and next time when you ask question please be specific.

Comment: In my question I have clearly stated that i have multiple TRs and on click i want to get the respective values against the anchor tag click i.e. respective vales of sstart and eend classes

Comment: Respective doesn't meant you need to read specific classes anchor tag what is that. You could just simply said I want to read these class values simple. And the way you have asked the question is kind of confusing to the person reading it that's why I'm the only person who has posted an answer.

Comment: Apologies for that then. This is my first question.

Comment: NP buddy every mistake is a learning path just see if the answer works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. I finally found the answer. Thank you for your time in helping me out.

Comment: This or from some where else m8.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out the answer.
I binded the ids of the data with the timepicker ids so every timepicker ids are different now. So, i just get the values from the timepicker ids.